# Side bar Menu with plus and minus icons on expand and collapse using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed a web page using HTML, CSS and Javascript but now I am facing a problem in adding plus/minus icon on collapse and expansion . I am not able to add these icons and I need to use only Javascript since I need to dump this pages in my hardware device. I tried to add plus/minus using javascript but its of no use. Could any one help me in solving this please ?

Please help me in solving this.

Here is the code :

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
  *{padding:0px;margin:2px;border-radius:7px;}
   body{font:16px/1 Times;background:#F8F8F8;width:220px;position:absolute;}
   ul{list-style: none;}
   li{position:relative;line-height:8px;}
   a{display:block;color:#000;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 12px;}
   li a:hover{background:#E2ECF6;font-weight:bold;color:#000;}
   ul ul{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);padding-left:10px;overflow:hidden;display:none;}
   </style><title>GW e EFM</title>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function openInFrame(url)
   {
         if(url=="Logout.html")
         {
            top.top.location = url; 
         }
         else
         {
           top.frames['WelcomeFrame'].location.href = url;
         }
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <ul id="example_tree">
   <li><span><a href="#">+ Configuration</a></span>
      <ul>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("SysConfig.html")'>System</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href="#">+ Line</a></span><ul><li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("LineConf.html")'>Line Config</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("ChannelSel.html")'>Channel</a></span></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span><a href="#">+ Ethernet Switch</a></span>
  <ul>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("PortConf.html")'>Port</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("VLANConf.html")'>VLAN &amp; QOS</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("MACTable.html")'>MAC Table</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("PortMirror.html")'>Port Mirroring</a></span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("SNMPConf.html")'>SNMP</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("CurrConf.html")'>Current</a></span></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
    <li><span><a href="#">+ System Control</a></span>
    <ul>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Save.html")'>Save</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Reboot.html")'>Reboot</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Factdefault.html")'>Factory Defaults</a></span></li>
     <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("UserAccount.html")'>Change Password</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("SysMaintain.html")'>System Maintenance</a></span></li>
   </ul></li>
   <li><span><a href="#">+ Diagnostics</a></span>
   <ul>
   <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Loopback.html")'>Loopback</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("TestPattern.html")'>Test Pattern</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("PingTrace.html")'>Ping/Trace Route</a></span></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Logout.html")'>Exit</a></span></li></ul></body>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var allSpan = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
  for(var i = 0; i < allSpan.length; i++)
  {
     allSpan[i].onclick=function()
     {
       if(this.parentNode)
       {
           var childList = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul');
           for(var j = 0; j< childList.length;j++)
           {
              var currentState = childList[j].style.display;
              if(currentState=="none" || currentState =="")
              { 
                 childList[j].style.display="block";
                 break;                                                                       
              }
              else 
              {
                  childList[j].style.display="none";
                  break;
              }
           }
       }
       }}
       </script></html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol this link may solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your codes with two corrections:

1. Changing the logic of currentstate checking.
2. replacing + and - onclick (caution: this mat replace unwanted - and + signs within your texts.) . You have to use minus sign initially if menus are expanded by default.

```js
var allSpan = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
  for(var i = 0; i < allSpan.length; i++)
  {
     allSpan[i].onclick=function()
     {
       if(this.parentNode)
       {
           var childList = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul');
           for(var j = 0; j< childList.length;j++)
           {
            
              var currentState = childList[j].style.display;
              if(currentState=="block" || currentState=="")
              {
                  childList[j].style.display="none";
                  this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace("-","+")
                  break;
              }
              else 
              {
                childList[j].style.display="block";
                 this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace("+","-")
                 break;
              }
           }
       }
 
 }
       
 }
```

```html
<ul id="example_tree">
   <li><span><a href="#">- Configuration</a></span>
      <ul>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("SysConfig.html")'>System</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href="#">- Line</a></span><ul><li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("LineConf.html")'>Line Config</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("ChannelSel.html")'>Channel</a></span></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span><a href="#">- Ethernet Switch</a></span>
  <ul>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("PortConf.html")'>Port</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("VLANConf.html")'>VLAN &amp; QOS</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("MACTable.html")'>MAC Table</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("PortMirror.html")'>Port Mirroring</a></span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("SNMPConf.html")'>SNMP</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("CurrConf.html")'>Current</a></span></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
    <li><span><a href="#">- System Control</a></span>
    <ul>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Save.html")'>Save</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Reboot.html")'>Reboot</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Factdefault.html")'>Factory Defaults</a></span></li>
     <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("UserAccount.html")'>Change Password</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("SysMaintain.html")'>System Maintenance</a></span></li>
   </ul></li>
   <li><span><a href="#">- Diagnostics</a></span>
   <ul>
   <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Loopback.html")'>Loopback</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("TestPattern.html")'>Test Pattern</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("PingTrace.html")'>Ping/Trace Route</a></span></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 <li><span><a href='javascript:openInFrame("Logout.html")'>Exit</a></span></li></ul>
```

You may add `allSpan[i].click();` inside the loop to simulate a fake click and change the initial state of menus from open to close.

Comment: Thanks a lot : ) but for the first time I need to have + and onclick (when expands) it should change to minus.

Comment: Ok. Please check the last paragraph I added about changing the default state. @SowmyaKaparthi